# Resource Owner flow OIDC Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, openid-connect

I've been asked to build an SPA which authenticates the user via OpenId's Resource Owner Flow.

This is a Javascript SPA, React based. returned token will be utilised for API calls.

I've been pointed in the direction of OpenIdConect and specifically the oidc-client.js but I've also read that this flow has been deprecated..

Is that true?
If so is there any other route to use the IdentityServer for username/password signing WITHOUT redirecting and hence handling the login form within the app?

All docs I've found so far only concentrate on the Implicit, Authorization Code or occasionally Hybrid flows.

An yes, I realise Implicit is the advised route but the decision was made to keep login inside the SPA.

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3

Most front-end JS libraries will avoid resource owner flow because the specification is pretty clear that you should not use it on an untrusted platform (like a web browser).

Comment: Who is your ODIC provider? If it's controlled by your (or your company) then your users are already trusting you with their password. As long as the provider supports the password grant you can use the resource owner flow, but if you don't control the OIDC provider then using the resource owner flow is asking your users to trust you with their password unnecessarily